How to mock functions effectively in Jest?
I have a React project -- JavaScript only and no TypeScript -- I am attempting to test with Jest.
I have file A which references file B which in turn utilizes a function C from module "@D/E" which accesses and returns data I want to mock.
I have tried using the mocking approaches described in the documentation and which I found here on Stack Overflow. None appear to work. For example:
In testFile.test.js:
import A from './A';

jest.mock('@D/E', () => ({
    C: jest.fn(() => ({
        field1: {},
        field2: [1, 2, 3]
    }))
}));

test("test name", () => {
    render(<A />);
});

In A.js:
const A = () => {
    return <B />;
}

export default A;

In B.js:
import C from '@D/E';

const B = () => {
    const f = C();
    // Do thing with 'f'
}

export default B;

When I run the test or walk through the debugger, I get Uncaught [TypeError: (0 , _e.C) is not a function].
What I was expecting was for C() to return { field1: {}, field2: [1, 2, 3] } instead of raising an exception.
Other recommendations appear to produce similar results, as do all other would-be solutions I have found while searching the internet. Can anyone point me in the direction of information to find an approach which will work?

The @D/E module uses default exports. So you should mock the @D/E module and the C like below:
jest.mock('@D/E', () =>
  jest.fn(() => ({
    field1: {},
    field2: [1, 2, 3],
  })),
);

Or,

When using the factory parameter for an ES6 module with a default export, the __esModule: true property needs to be specified. This property is normally generated by Babel / TypeScript, but here it needs to be set manually. When importing a default export, it's an instruction to import the property named default from the export object

jest.mock('@D/E', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(() => ({
      field1: {},
      field2: [1, 2, 3],
    })),
  };
});

